# Refresh a single div in rails using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to allow a user to click a button and add an item to a list. Rather than load the entire page again, I would just like the list to be refreshed. As of now, when the add button is clicked, the add_item method is called in the lists_controller:

**lists_controller.rb:**

```
  def add_item
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @list = params[:list]

    if @list.nil?
      @list = []
    end

    @list.append @product.name
    session[:active_list] = @list

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The correct product title is appended to the @list array.

In the div containing the list (#list-container) I have:

```
  <div class="col-md-3" id="list-container">
    <h3>List:</h3>
    <ol>
      <% @list.each do |item| %>
        <li><%= item %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
    <%= button_to 'Add to List', { controller: "lists", action: "add_item", params: { product_id: product.id, list: @list } }, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary add-item-btn' %>
```

I am using the following when the button is clicked

**add_item.js.erb**

```
// Clear active status from pressed button
$(".add-item-btn").blur()
$('#list-container').load('/my_controller/home #list-container')
```

to refresh the div.

When I click, nothing happens. No items are added to the list and the page remains unchanged. If I refresh the page, I see the item has been added to the list.

I cant simply append to the div, since I have a checkout button that resides under the last item when the page was loaded. If I append, all future items are added under this button.

Is there a way to render just that div?

**Edit1:**

Turns out I was getting a 404 error. I removed the 'my_controller/home' and since this is the root_path, it tried to load the entire home page into the #list-container div.

When I tried adding the id to the load function:

```
    $('#list-container').load('#list-container')
```

I still get the entire homepage being rendered within the div when I click a button.

**Edit2:**

Ok. I didn't have the get request routed in my routes.rb file before and I can now use:

```
$('#list-container').load('/my_controller/home #list-container')
```

Only catch is now, everything that was in the div is gone, and the whole thing is blank. I'm not sure what is causing that.

**Edit3:**

I almost got it. I nested a div.list in the #list-container and changed the jquery to:

```
$('#list-container').load('/static_pages/home #list-container .list')
```

Now when I click the button to add an item to the list, the item is added. There is a hangup though. If I try to add another item, the second click overwrites the first. For instance, if I have 7 items when I originally load the page, I can add item 8, but at that point I can only change item 8.

It is not until I refresh the page, that item 8 is saved and I can add item 9.

Comment: *"doesn't appear to be working"* is a very vague and uninformative problem statement that really tells us nothing. The concept shown is correct however so you need to isolate what part isn't working

Comment: Nothing at all happens. The page remains the same. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues (status and response body). Also, is there more server side output than what is shown? Try removing the `#list-container` in url and see what happens. Also add an error handler to the ajax ( load() )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! It looks like I'm getting a 404 error when searching for my_controller/home.

Comment: Then ajax (load) path is either incorrect or you have a server side routing issue. We don't know enough to help more

Comment: This is the root_path so I changed ...load('') and it loaded the entire home page into the div. If I add the id I get the same result.

Comment: can also test path directly in browser address bar manually

Answer (score 0):

render add_item.js.erb from the corresponding action in corresponding controller.

```
respond_to do |format|
format.js {
render 'add_item.js.erb'
  }
end
```

Also, instead of having to add respond to format.js im the controller, I usually add that directly in routes.rb as:

```
get 'ajax/:model', to: 'ajax#:model', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Third, I don't see any remote: true, anywhere?

Comment: I guess I missed remote: true when copying and pasting. I have updated my code.

Comment: In your routes.rb - add this on the same line as get model#add_item (or what you have there) sepparated with a comma: ':as => :list_item'
and then on the button, add:  ':url => list_item_path', - Also button_to's are tricky. You might want to add method: 'GET' or method: 'PATCH' too.